# type universe cannot resolve assembly opening project in vs2022

Tags: asp.net, .net, dotnet-httpclient, c#-2.0

[image]

I am trying to open my old project developed in VS 2010 and dot net framework 2.0 when i open design view I get this error how to resolve this issue

Comment: Please post the code  or error as text in your question, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

are you importing that one web page, or just attempting to open this project? Perhaps this is a web site, and not a web site application project?

Thus, try opening with this:

[image]

This may well be a web site - not a web site application.

You could also close that web page, and from build menu, try a re-build solution, and then see if the page can be opened. (I would try this idea first).